# Problems trying to populate sub form question fields with answers

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

First time poster here.  I have been working on my first project for the last few months.  And have spent an absorbent amount of time trying to get this one piece to work.  I am able to display my configuration which has a drop down for config type.  Depending on the Type selected it will display a list of "Attributes" (Questions) and I would like to have my form so that I can pick a type of config and answer the questions that pertain to that config.  The part I am getting stuck on is the line in my view attrib_obj       = get_object_or_404(config_attribs, id=1).  This will display the first answer correctly for evey config because I hard coded it to show the answer to 1 but it will then display the first answer to every question.  I am struggling on how to make this variable to be the id for every question and not just the first one.  Thank you for any help.  Oh and since i am new to this i am not sure if i am saving my form correctly either.  :)  [Visual of my Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGcg3.png)

**My Model**

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    config_type         = models.ForeignKey('ConfigType', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    company             = models.ForeignKey('companies.Company', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("configurations:configuration-update", kwargs={"id": self.id})


class ConfigType(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    inactive        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Attribute(models.Model):
    config_type     = models.ForeignKey('ConfigType', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    number          = models.IntegerField()
    attribute       = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    input_type      = models.ForeignKey('InputType', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    required        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #answer             = models.ManyToManyField('Answer')  
    inactive        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.attribute


class InputType(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Answer(models.Model):
    configuration   = models.ForeignKey('Configuration', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    attribute       = models.ForeignKey('Attribute', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)   
    text            = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    checkbox        = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    number          = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date            = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.configuration.name + " - Attribute #" + str(self.attribute.number)
```

**My View**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def configuration_update_view(request, id=id):
    obj             = get_object_or_404(Configuration, id=id)
    config_attribs  = obj.config_type.attribute_set.all()   
    attrib_obj      = get_object_or_404(config_attribs, id=1)
    config_answers  = obj.answer_set.all()
    answer_obj      = get_object_or_404(config_answers, attribute=attrib_obj)
    form            = ConfigurationForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    attrib_form     = ConfigAttribForm(request.POST or None, instance=answer_obj)   
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    if attrib_form.is_valid():
        attrib_form.save()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'attrib_form': attrib_form,
        'config_answers': config_answers,
        'config_attribs': config_attribs        
    }
    return render(request, "configurations/configuration_detail.html", context)
```

Comment: How do you know which attrib_obj to fetch? If that's the problem, how would you like to fetch that, ignoring any technical constraints?

Comment: I have a for loop in my html.  {% for attribute in config_attribs %}  And it lists all the questions number, question and answer.  But I am struggling with the answer part because my form I w ant to associate the id of the question to the answer that matches it.

Comment: If you only have one that you're modifying, you can change the view and url to allow the ConfigAttribute's id to also be supplied in the url.

Comment: I replaced that like of code with this: for attrib in config_attribs:
  attrib_obj = (Q(id=attrib), Q.OR)

Comment: The code I changed didnt get me any further.  I cant get my form answers to be matched to my questions.  I was hoping to get the id of my questions to match the answers.questuions.id  Any help would be appreciated!